# Always display text on two lines

Tags: flutter, text, multiline

I have `Text`:

```
Text(
  "My long ... long ... text",
  style: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
  maxLines: 2,
),
```

In case text is long, it will be displayed on two lines only. My question is: is it possible to, in case of short text, to take the same space as this long text (as two lines)? I need to calculate the height and therefore I need to take into account two lines everytime. Also in case there is only short text. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: did you try adding `\n` for a new line at the end? `Text(${myString}\n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\n` to create a new line at the end.

```
 Text(
   '${myString}\n'
 ),
```